# javascript HTML table conditional data pull

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for a few days.
(the biggest reason is that you haven't learned the logic of JS yet "I'm not a programmer, just a hobby").

I have an 8 column 56 row in my table.

When I click on the row I want in the 8th column, I can pull the data to input2, but I want to pull the 2nd cell of the same row to input1.
How should I write code?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myTable td').click(function () {
    column_num = parseInt($(this).index()) + 1;
    row_num = parseInt($(this).parent().index()) + 1;
    // T=rows[row_num].cells.item(2).innerHTML);
    // T="Row_num =" + row_num + "  ,  Rolumn_num ="+ 2 ;
    // T=rows[row_num].cells.item(2).innerHTML);
    // T=("myTable".rows[18].cells[2].innerHTML);
    // T=("myTable".rows[18].cells[2].innerText);
    // T="myTable".rows[18].cells[2].firstChild.value;
    // T=document.getElementById('myTable').rows[row_num].cells[2].data);
    T = myTable.rows[18].cells[2].innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('input1').value = T.toFixed(2);
  });
});

$('#myTable').click(function (e) {
  if (column_num == 8) {
    document.getElementById('input2').value = $(e.target).text();
  }
});
```

```html
<table width="700" onclick="myFun(event)" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="10" width="832">
        SAC KALINLIKLARINA G&Ouml;RE SOLIDWORKS KANAL
        &Ouml;L&Ccedil;&Uuml;LERİ&nbsp; RADYUS KALINLIKLA AYNI GIRILECEK
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="center">
      <td width="25">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="65">KALINLIK (mm)</td>
      <td width="70">MALZEME</td>
      <td width="70">UZAMA (mm)</td>
      <td width="40">KANAL</td>

      <td width="75">EN K&Uuml;&Ccedil;&Uuml;K B&Uuml;K&Uuml;M</td>
      <td width="75">EN K&Uuml;&Ccedil;&Uuml;K TERS B&Uuml;K&Uuml;M</td>
      <td width="75">K-FACTOR</td>
      <td width="75">MAKS UZUNLUK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0,6</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,4</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0,7</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,65</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,05</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0,8</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,4</td>
      <td>V5</td>

      <td>3,5mm</td>
      <td>7,3mm</td>
      <td>0,43</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0,8</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,65</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>5,2mm</td>
      <td>7,5mm</td>
      <td>0,24</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,64</td>
      <td>V5</td>

      <td>4mm</td>
      <td>6,8mm</td>
      <td>0,5</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,86</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>5,5mm</td>
      <td>7,80mm</td>
      <td>0,3625</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>r15</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,78</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>1,87</td>
      <td>V5</td>

      <td>5mm</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>9</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>2,12</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>5,7mm</td>
      <td>9mm</td>
      <td>0,4219</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>1,2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>2,49</td>
      <td>V12</td>

      <td>8mm</td>
      <td>10,1mm</td>
      <td>0,2203</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>V5</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0.66</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>12</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>2,5</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>6mm</td>
      <td>8,1mm</td>
      <td>0,4855</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>2,78</td>
      <td>V12</td>

      <td>8,1mm</td>
      <td>10,2mm</td>
      <td>0,4514</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>11,4mm</td>
      <td>15,2mm</td>
      <td>0,275</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>9,75</td>
      <td>r15</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,15</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>16</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>3,42</td>
      <td>V12</td>

      <td>9mm</td>
      <td>11,5mm</td>
      <td>0,4578</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>3,72</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>11,4mm</td>
      <td>15,2mm</td>
      <td>0,3623</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>3,72</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>11,4mm</td>
      <td>15,2mm</td>
      <td>0,255</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>8,6</td>
      <td>r15</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,79</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>r20</td>

      <td>35mm</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,709</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2,5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>4,36</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>11,7mm</td>
      <td>15.7mm</td>
      <td>0,4311</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>4,6</td>
      <td>V12</td>

      <td>10mm</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,57</td>
      <td rowspan="6" width="88">Boy 1500mm den kısa olacak</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>23</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>4,98</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>12mm</td>
      <td>16.1mm</td>
      <td>0,4854</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>5,57</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>17mm</td>
      <td>20.7mm</td>
      <td>0,36445</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>6,15</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,593</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>26</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>6,94</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>17.5mm</td>
      <td>21.5mm</td>
      <td>0,44195</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>7,8</td>
      <td>V35</td>

      <td>23,3mm</td>
      <td>36mm</td>
      <td>0,3051</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>7,2</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,63</td>
      <td rowspan="8" width="88">Boy 300mm den kısa olacak</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>8,2</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,503</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>9,35</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,554</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: orange; color: black">
      <td>31</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>10,2</td>
      <td>V35</td>

      <td>25mm</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,464</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>V50</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0.432</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>16,4</td>
      <td>V50</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,5025</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>34</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>18,6</td>
      <td>V80</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,3625</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>DKP</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>V50</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0.5702</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>1.5</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>2,5</td>
      <td>V8&nbsp;</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,485</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>BAKIR</td>
      <td>3,8</td>
      <td>V12</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,336</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>BAKIR</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0.49</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>BAKIR</td>
      <td>8,2</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,503</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>BAKIR</td>
      <td>14,4</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,63</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>8,6</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>18mm</td>
      <td>25mm</td>
      <td>0,451</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>6,2</td>
      <td>V16&nbsp;</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>18.5 mm</td>
      <td>0.5596</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>5,4</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,385</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>3,8</td>
      <td>V12</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0.337</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>2.5</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>4,84</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,315</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>1,5</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>2,75</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,38</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>PSL</td>
      <td>2,1</td>
      <td>V8</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,21</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>AL&Uuml;</td>
      <td>9,5</td>
      <td>r15</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>0,76</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>AL&Uuml;</td>
      <td>4,98</td>
      <td>V16</td>

      <td>12mm</td>
      <td>16.1mm</td>
      <td>0,4854</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>POLI</td>
      <td>6,4</td>
      <td>V25</td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>528</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [How should I write code?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) isn't a valid question

Comment: Your HTML markup does not support the question. Where are the `input` elements?

Comment: Hello, I apologize for my mistakes, I am not used to using the forum yet.

Comment: Not a problem but please clarify the layout of the HTML to illustrate your actual need. Do these `input` elements exist within each table row? Does each `td` contain an `input` element?

Comment: I do not see a single `input` element and have no idea about the `edit` function

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myTable tr td').click(function(e)
{
document.getElementById("input2").value = this.innerHTML;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">


  <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r1c1 </td>
        <td>r1c2</td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r2c1</td>
        <td>r2c2</td>
        <td>r2c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r3c1</td>
        <td>r3c2</td>
        <td>r3c3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input id="input2" >
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, I could not show all of the actual codes because there are many. i can get the data of the cell i clicked, no problem so far.
I will try to explain what I want to do with an example.
8th column-4. When I click on the row (row4-cell8), I can pull the data in the cell to input2. and at the same time, I want to pull the data from the 2nd column of the same row (4row-cell2) to input1.

Comment: What `input` elements?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, I edited the codes you used, but I can't add the new version, the edit function doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

From the markup given and description is this more or less what you were hoping to accomplish? Added some css for clarity to show which cells / items are affected

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr:not([class="headers"])').forEach(n=>n.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  let eighth=this.querySelector('td:nth-child(8)');
  let second=this.querySelector('td:nth-child(2) input');
  let first=this.querySelector('td:nth-child(1) input');
  
  first.value=second.value;
  second.value=eighth.textContent;
  eighth.textContent='';
  
  [ first, second, eighth, this ].forEach( n=>n.classList.add('mod') );
}))
```

```css
tr{cursor:pointer}
th,td{padding:0.5rem;margin:0.25rem;}
td{border:1px dotted grey}
td.mod,input.mod{background:pink}
tr.mod{background:yellow}
input{width:100px}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='headers'>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
        <th>col4</th>
        <th>col5</th>
        <th>col6</th>
        <th>col7</th>
        <th>col8</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='r1c1' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='r1c2' /></td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
        <td>r1c4</td>
        <td>r1c5</td>
        <td>r1c6</td>
        <td>r1c7</td>
        <td>r1c8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='r2c1' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='r2c2' /></td>
        <td>r2c3</td>
        <td>r2c4</td>
        <td>r2c5</td>
        <td>r2c6</td>
        <td>r2c7</td>
        <td>r2c8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' value='r3c1' /></td>
        <td><input type='text' value='r3c2' /></td>
        <td>r3c3</td>
        <td>r3c4</td>
        <td>r3c5</td>
        <td>r3c6</td>
        <td>r3c7</td>
        <td>r3c8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from the javascript side at the moment - you seem to be using a combination of jQuery and plain javascript; that's not particularly an issue, but it's nice to be consistent.

So, if we lean more towards the jQuery (doesn't make a massive difference, but jQuery makes some things easier to implement), you can tweak the `$(document).ready` function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable td").click(function() {

        column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
        row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;
        T= $('myTable').rows[row_num].cells[2].data; //The next line replaces this value, so what's the point in this line?
        T= $('myTable').rows[18].cells[2].text(); //pretty sure you only want the associated text, not any nested HTML blocks
       
        $('input1').val(T.toFixed(2));                   
    });
});
```

Then this `if` statement can be tweaked:

```
    if (column_num == 8){
        $('input2').val($(e.target).text());  
    }
```

Now the big question is: You have three different click events on that table... Why?

You could just combine it to one click event (I'll also throw some generic HTML block in for the inputs since you left them out of the question):

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r1c1 </td>
        <td>r1c2</td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r2c1</td>
        <td>r2c2</td>
        <td>r2c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r3c1</td>
        <td>r3c2</td>
        <td>r3c3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="input-row">
    <input id="input1" />
    <input id="input2" />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myTable td").click(function() {

            column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
            row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;
            T= $('myTable').rows[row_num].cells[2].data; //The next line replaces this value, so what's the point in this line?
            T= $('myTable').rows[18].cells[2].text(); //pretty sure you only want the associated text, not any nested HTML blocks
           
            $('input1').val(T.toFixed(2));                   
            if (column_num == 8){
                $('input2').val($(e.target).text());
            }

            //If MyFun does something else, call it here 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can i upload html file here. whole project one file (1 page) 25KB

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you to everyone who replied. I realize that I haven't been able to explain the question in detail.
 A code I found now solved my problem.
```

```
   $(document).ready(function()
       {
           $("#myTable td").click(function()
           {
                column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
                row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;
                //T= $('myTable').rows[row_num].cells[2].innerHTML;
                //T= $(this).rows[row_num].cells[2].innerHTML;           
               document.getElementById("input1").value = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[row_num].cells[1].innerHTML; // this is correct            
           });
       });
```